# Exclude from build in CLion

Tags: c++, compilation, clion

Is it possible to exclude a file in the project from build without deleting it in Clion ? This is similar to exclude from build option in visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLion uses CMake as its build system. You can open CMakeLists.txt and find:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
        main.cpp
        #my_file_to_exclude.cpp
    )
```

section, then remove or comment out this file from list. Dont forget to click `Reload Changes` button after makeing changes and before rebuild.

Comment: There is no "set(" in my CMakeList.txt